# how to filter brands by categories in bigcommerce?

Tags: php, api, e-commerce, bigcommerce

Is there any way to filter brands names by categories in bigcommerce?
i get all brands names list as

%%Panel.SideShopByBrandFull%%

but now i want to filter it by category

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to display brands which have products assigned in a given category.